# Having problem configuring laravel in NGINX sublocation

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

My application includes a vue only frontend with api written in laravel. The way I want to set it up like this:

`http://myapp.local` --> Points to the vue frontend.

`http://myapp.local/api` --> Points to the laravel application api routes.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.local *.myapp.local;
    root /var/www/myapp-frontend/dist;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ^~ /api {
        alias /var/www/myapp-api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
     }

     location @api {
        rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 last;
     }

     location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Hitting `http://myapp.local/api` opens the root laravel route. But if I open any other route in my application I get an **500 Internal Server
Error**.

This is the error in nginx's error log:

```
2019/09/09 15:58:18 [error] 20954#20954: *10 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@api", client:
127.0.0.1, server: myapp.local, request: "GET /api/admin/features HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.local"
```

**Update**

I have managed to make it work somehow, this is what the updated config looks like

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name *.myapp.local;
    root /var/www/myapp-api/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    add_header X-debug-request-filename "$request_filename" always;
    add_header X-debug-document-root "$document_root" always;
    add_header X-debug-fastcgi-script-name "$fastcgi_script_name" always;
    add_header X-debug-query-string "$query_string" always;

     location / {
        root /var/www/myapp-frontend/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
     }

     location /api {
        alias /var/www/myapp-api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;

        add_header X-debug-request-filename "$request_filename" always;
        add_header X-debug-document-root "$document_root" always;
        add_header X-debug-fastcgi-script-name "$fastcgi_script_name" always;
        add_header X-debug-query-string "$query_string" always;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
     }

     location @api {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$  /api/index.php?/$1 last; # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
     }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    #error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have one small problem though, everytime I access the api routes I need to write `/api` twice in order to get the correct address. For example like this `http://myapp.local/api/api/login`. `/api/login` is the actual route, and `http://myapp.local/api/` points to the laravel application, so needing to write `/api` twice makes sense. But would it be anyhow possible to just use `http://myapp.local/api/login` to access `/api/login` route?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `location /` for the vue.js interpreter

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.local *.myapp.local;
    root /var/www/myapp-frontend/dist;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ^~ /api {
        alias /var/www/myapp-api/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
     }

     location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
    }

     location @api {
        rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 last;
     }

     location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Used the port `3000` as example in here. Set it to your node listening port.

Comment: Because we have an wildcard subdomain setup. Its a multitenant application and each teneant would be assigned a separate subdomain.

Comment: @SayantanDas Try setting the `location /`

Comment: The vue application does not run as a server. Its statically generated in the `/var/www/myapp-frontend/dist` folder.